# Visual Studio creates a property instead of a method event handler. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I just had VS generate an event handler for me, and it created a property instead of a method. I don't understand that. I just tried a separate test in VS 2012, and it worked as expected.

First, this is my test that worked as I thought it would:

```
private static void EventTest()
{
    Geek skeet = new Geek();

    skeet.SomeEvent += skeet_SomeEvent;
}
```

When I had VS generate the handler for me, it created this.

```
static void skeet_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

That makes sense. That method will be called when the event is invoked.

Now, the problem... I'm working on an existing project, in VS 2010, and when I do the same thing (have VS generate the handler):

```
private void SubscribeToPlcDataChangeEvents()
{
    _plc.PlcLoggerEventHandler += _plcLoggerEventHandler;
}
```

It creates a property:

```
public EventHandler<PlcLoggerEventArgs> _plcLoggerEventHandler { get; set; }
```

Why? I don't get that. I want to handle the event in a method.

**EDIT - This is how the event handler is declared:**

```
public event EventHandler<PlcLoggerEventArgs> PlcLoggerEventHandler;
```

Comment: Can you show how `_plc.PlcLoggerEventHandler` is declared?

Comment: As in you hit Tab twice and it made this?

Comment: @sixlettervariables That's correct.

Comment: @DaveShaw I just added it to my question.

Comment: No repro on VS2k10 here. Do you have any add-ins/extensions?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Actually, hit tab twice made it work. For the one that was giving me a problem, I was hitting alt-shift-f10, which is the equivalent of hovering over the red squiggly code and choosing options and having the code generated. Still, why a property? How does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice you will notice that it is generated "properly" in cases of event handlers.

In the case where you use the "Options to help bind the item" shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in Visual Studio 2010, your two possible actions in this case are:

- Generate property stub for 'PlcLoggerEventHandler' in ...
- Generate field stub for 'PlcLoggerEventHandler' in ...

So, the fact that a property is then created when you use this seems to be By Design, even though in the case of an event handler it makes no sense.